# Python move (pop) single dictionary item into new dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and don't know the keys or values.  I want to remove a single element (doesn't matter which) and create a new dictionary containing only that key and value, removing it from the old dictionary in the process.

dict(n items) -> newdict(1 item) and dict(n-1 items)

What I've tried:

1. `newdict=dict.pop()` - Would work perfectly for a list, but for dictionary it 1. requires a key and only returns a value, not a new dictionary or a key, value pair
2. `newdict={dict.items()[0]}` - TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable
3. `newdict={dict.keys()[0],dict.pop(dict.keys()[0])}` - TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
4. `key=list(dict)[0] newdict={key,dict.pop(key)}` - Works (finally), but isn't their a better way than converting the entire dictionary to a list just to grab one key?

Is there a more efficient way to move a single dictionary element into a new dictionary?

Edit: Having the single element as a tuple would also work.  I just need both the key and value of the element I remove.

Comment: You can use `next(iter(old_dict))` to get the key of a single element and use it to remove from `old_dict` and add to `new_dict`.

Comment: @Georgy Yes, as it turns out it does, though I had previously glanced at that question and thought that it would only help access, not remove.  Izaak's answer below also answers my question.

Comment: I went ahead and voted to close, though I do think that others looking to pop/remove instead of access might also miss the answer in the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good use-case for `dict.popitem`:

```
old_dict = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
new_dict = {7: 8}

def move_item(old, new):
    k, v = old.popitem()
    new[k] = v

move_item(old_dict, new_dict)
print(old_dict, new_dict)
```

with result

```
{1: 2, 3: 4} {7: 8, 5: 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
for key, value in old_dict:
    new_dict[key] = old_dict.pop(key)
    # operate with new_dict
```

Comment: Hi there! I think perhaps you're being a little overzealous with the `=` signs `:)` (just one would do)

Comment: My function is basically creating a Venn diagram from an arbitrary number of named sets.  Order doesn't matter and the sets should have names (keys), so a dictionary seems like the obvious choice.  The way the function operates is by removing one element from the dictionary, computing the venn diagram groups for the (n-1) sets, and intersecting the new set with each.  Am I missing something, or is this a situation where popping an element from a dictionary is useful?

Comment: I think you are right, a dictionary seems to be the correct choice. I was trying to answer to the theoretical question of 'how to remove an item from a dict and create a new one with that item'. Knowing what you are doing, I think you can just iterate over the dict items. I will update my response to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate

```py
for key, value in dict.items():
    if value == bla:
        dict.pop(key)
```